# Pass binary data from web page to Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to pass large binary data (e.g. new Uint8Array(10000000)) from web page's JavaScript (JS) to extension's JS. I want these data to be saved from extension to a file by nsIBinaryOutputStream/nsIFile (which I can't call from my page). [ATM I don't know about any other method how to save (large/binary) data from page's JS on local machine.]

I've red about an [Interaction between privileged and non-privileged pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages), but it is useful only for passing strings. I don't think that converting 10MB from/to base64 is good idea.

- Is it even possible to pass such data to extension?
- If yes, how to do it then?
- Shouldn't I use [JS XPCOM component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/How_to_Build_an_XPCOM_Component_in_Javascript)?

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: You are concerned with the security implications of accessing the typed array from chrome or you are asking how to save it?

Comment: @paa I am asking how to pass array from page's JS to extension's JS (as you say, "chrome") for further processing in an extension (saving them to file with in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've solved how to pass *any* object from webpage to extension.

In web page JavaScript (JS):

```
var element = document.createElement("foo");
document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
event.initCustomEvent("bar", true, false, anyObject);
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In extension JS:

```
document.addEventListener("bar", function(e) {
  // use e.detail here
 }, false, true);
```

[Proof of concept here.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/auxilliary-file-saver/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in file, you can use `nsIWebBrowserPersist` and download data directly to a file. This file can be zipped, and it's possible to unzip it. A lot of informations (with examples) you can find on these pages:

[download file using nsiWebBrowserPersist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Downloading_Files)

[unzip file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk%3aXPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIZipReader)

Comment: _If you have data in file_
I don't. Actually I need to save data to file :) Data are stored in page-scope JS variable (which typeof is some array, e.g. Uint8Array) and I want pass them to extension-scope JS.

Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: So I think the only solution is converting with base64 and send to extension or cut them in portions and send or send them immediately after small update (after add e.g. 1000 items).